# Passing parameter to controller in MVC with no changes in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.ReloadedFromEmailForm = id;

        return View();
    }
```

The controller can be called from RouteConfig (as its default) with param `id = null` and can be called from some other controller which is returning

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {id = 1});
```

Now I want to get that `id = 1` but in my url when I turn on app, to set just like regular without any param.

How to achieve that?

Now: `localhost:8888/Index/1`

What I want: `localhost:8888/Index/` (but still I want to fill in ViewBag).

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I didn't realize that property name `id` already in a route config,and automatically maps in url. All I needed to do was to change my prop to anything else, like foobar :)